# iOS – Upload to AWS S3 synchronously

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

All the aws-sdk-ios examples use the `AWSS3TransferManager` to upload data *asynchronously*.

For example: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/blob/master/S3TransferManager-Sample/Swift/S3TransferManagerSampleSwift/UploadViewController.swift#L81

Now usually, this is good, but my work is already in an `NSOperation` subclass for other reasons, so I'd like to upload to S3 synchronously to keep things simple (otherwise, I'd need to implement an asynchronous `NSOperation`, and that has a lot more boilerplate...)

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In case anyone is curious, I figured it out:

```
    let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: AWSRegionType.USEast1,
                                                            identityPoolId: AwsCognitoIdentityPoolId)
    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: AWSRegionType.USEast1,
                                                credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
    AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

    let S3Client = AWSS3.defaultS3()
    let putObjectRequest = AWSS3PutObjectRequest()
    putObjectRequest.bucket = AwsBucketName
    putObjectRequest.key = key
    putObjectRequest.body = logFilePathURL

    do {
        let fileAttributes = try self.fileManager.attributesOfItemAtPath(logFilePathURL.path!)
        let fileSizeNumber = fileAttributes[NSFileSize] as! NSNumber
        putObjectRequest.contentLength = NSNumber(longLong: fileSizeNumber.longLongValue)
    } catch _ as NSError {
        // TODO handle error
    }

    S3Client.putObject(putObjectRequest).continueWithBlock { (task: AWSTask) -> AnyObject? in
        return nil
    }.waitUntilFinished()
```

...yeah. I wasn't able to find an example *anywhere*, so I had to read the source and figure things out. As for that `aws-sdk-ios` library, talk about over-engineering... It took a while to figure it out through all those layers of indirection.

Anyways, in that final block where I `return nil` is where you'd handle errors, etc.

Comment: After wasting a lot of time, this was actually all I needed to do! Great simple answer.