# Calling an AWS Lambda function via APIGateway synchronously in Swift

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

I am able to asynchronously invoke AWS lambda functions in my code like so:

```
var r = IPInputToResourceGetSpots()
r.latitude = 37.8050638 //destination.latitude
r.longitude = -122.2972835 //destination.longitude
r.radius = 1000

let client = IPIOSAppAPIClient.defaultClient()

var results:IPOutputToResourceGetSpots = IPOutputToResourceGetSpots()
client.resourcegetspotsPost(r).continueWithExecutor(AWSExecutor.mainThreadExecutor(), withBlock: { (task: AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in

//Deal with return of AWS function
return task
})
```

But what I want is to invoke the code synchronously and have the code pause when the AWS function is called until the call has been completed. I have tried changing this line:

```
client.resourcegetspotsPost(r).continueWithExecutor(AWSExecutor.mainThreadExecutor(), withBlock: { (task: AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
```

with:

```
client.resourcegetspotsPost(r).continueWithBlock({ (task: AWSTask!) -> AWSTask! in
```

But both seem to be asynchronous...

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the post below, and incorporating waitUntilFinished()

[AWSTask Synchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186402/ios-upload-to-aws-s3-synchronously)